# Matrix 2D on Convolutional Netowrk

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

that may be a silly question, but I wanted to use a convolutional neural network in my deep reinforcement learning project and I got a problem I don't understand.
In my project I want to insert into network matrix `6x7` which should be equivalent to black and white picture of 6x7 size (42 pixels) right?

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = torch.nn.Sequential()
        self.model.add_module("conv_1", torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=4, stride = 1))
        self.model.add_module("relu_1", torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.model.add_module("max_pool", torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2))
        self.model.add_module("conv_2", torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=16, kernel_size=4, stride = 1))
        self.model.add_module("relu_2", torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.model.add_module("flatten", torch.nn.Flatten())

        self.model.add_module("linear", torch.nn.Linear(in_features=16*16*16, out_features=7))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        return x
```

In `conv1` `in_channels=1` because I have got only 1 matrix (if it was image recognition that means 1 color). Other `in_channels` and `out_channels` are kind of random until `linear`.  I have no idea where I should insert the size of a matrix, but the final output should be a size of `7` which i typed in `linear`.

The error i get is:

```
RuntimeError: Expected 3D (unbatched) or 4D (batched) input to conv2d, but got input of size: [6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First, the reason you're getting that error message is because the CNN is expecting a tensor with shape `(N, Cin, Hin, Win)`, where:

- `N` is the batch size
- `Cin` is the number of input channels
- `Hin` is the input image pixel height
- `Win` is the input image pixel width

You're only providing the `width` and `height` dimensions. You need to explicitly add a `channels` and `batch` dimension, even if the value of those dimensions is only `1`:

```py
model = CNN()

example_input = torch.randn(size=(6, 7)) # this is your input image

print(example_input.shape) # should be (6, 7)

output = model(example_input) # you original error

example_input = example_input.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0) # adds batch and channels dimension

print(example_input.shape) # should now be (1, 1, 6, 7)

output = model(example_input) # no more error!
```

You'll note however, you get a different error now:

```
RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (1 x 2). Kernel size: (4 x 4). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size
```

This is because after the first conv layer, your data is of shape `1x2`, but your kernel size for the second layer is `4`, which makes the operation impossible. An input image of size `6x7` is quite small, either reduce the kernel size to something that works, or use a larger images.

Here's a working example:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn


class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = torch.nn.Sequential()
        self.model.add_module(
            "conv_1",
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=2, stride=1),
        )
        self.model.add_module("relu_1", torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.model.add_module("max_pool", torch.nn.MaxPool2d(2))
        self.model.add_module(
            "conv_2",
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=16, kernel_size=2, stride=1),
        )
        self.model.add_module("relu_2", torch.nn.ReLU())
        self.model.add_module("flatten", torch.nn.Flatten())

        self.model.add_module("linear", torch.nn.Linear(in_features=32, out_features=7))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        return x


model = CNN()
x = torch.randn(size=(6, 7))
x = x.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
output = model(x)
print(output.shape) # has shape (1, 7)
```

Note, I changed the `kernel_size` to 2, and the final linear layer has an input size of `32`. Also, the output has shape `(1, 7)`, the 1 is the batch_size, which in our case was only 1. If you want just the 7 output features, just use `x = torch.squeeze(x)`.

Comment: It seems to work but i have faced another problem.

I'm using it for reinforcement learning and I save every state of the game (which is my matrix) and pass it to model. After the game I get all states (matrices) and pass them to the model. To do so i convert them using `torch.tensor(np.array(state), dtype=torch.float)` and while its a single matrix it works, but when my `state` is an array of matrices i get `TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_.`

Before i used NN and my matrix was flattened and it worked (instead of array of matrices i had array of vectors)

Comment: That means `torch.tensor(np.array(state), dtype=torch.float)` works for a single vector, an array of vectors and single matrix but not for an array of matrices. Can i somehow make it work?